# Workflow extension NULL in GetInstanceExtensions<> method

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to retrieve a workflow extension once the workflow completes (in the workflow application Completed event) via the WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs GetInstanceExtensions<>() method.

For some reason, that method always returns null.  Is it not possible to retrieve the workflow extensions and their current values from the workflow completed event handler?

Answer (score 1):

I was using this code:

var ext = e.GetInstanceExtensions() as TaskResolutionExtension;

That wasn't working, but this does:

var ext = e.GetInstanceExtensions().ToList().First();